# Why is it okay for my .bashrc or .zshrc to be writable by my normal user?

Tags: linux, bash, security, zsh, npm

My user ~/.zshrc file has the following default privileges

```
-rw-r--r--
```

My understanding of user permissions is that any process spawned by my user will then have read/write permissions to this file.

In malicious hands this could probably be used to edit aliases or append a directory of the attackers choosing to the beginning of the $PATH. I'm concerned that a malicious program that I install on the user level could then trick me into somehow giving up my sudo password through this method.

Obviously I do trust most of the programs that I install to not be malicious, however, I do use npm as a package manager for my own projects which is commonly accepted to be a vector for malware due to the sheer number of dependencies each module and it's dependencies can have.

I know that running `sudo npm install -g` is really bad practice but is using npm as a user which has write access to your main shell configuration file almost as bad just with a few extra steps in between, or am I lacking an understanding of how user permissions/shell configuration/npm works?

If this is insecure, then have I somehow missed security good practice for handling node js projects?

Comment: If you don't trust a program it shouldn't be run under your account.  Create a different account and run it from there.  Make a separate user for npm projects if you are really concerned.

Answer (score 2):

A program will be able to change permissions of your files. So, even if write permission is disabled, it does not matter…
Yes, a program will be able to do what it wants if you run it regularly.

To prevent that, you have several solutions. For instance, you can run it in a container, use cgroups or Linux namespaces.

If you want to check your config files, you can put them under versioning and check for modification when running new shell, or check some checksum. But, from my point of view, it is not a good solution since a malicious programs can do a lot of different hacks, and you will only be protected from one scenario.

Comment: From Scott Culp's “[Ten Immutable Laws of Security](https://www.wciapool.org/pdf/Tab_5_10_Immutable_LawsofSecurity.pdf)”, law #1: If a bad guy can persuade you to run his program on your computer, it’s not solely your computer anymore.

Answer (score 0):

> any process spawned by my user will then have read/write permissions

Yes, any program you run can modify your .zshrc file. It can read and write **any files that you own.**

Think about that for a minute. Getting sudo access would be bad, but the program can do a lot of damage without it.

... Do you trust the program to behave itself? If not, don't run it as yourself (and definitely not as root) on your machine.

> am I lacking an understanding of how user permissions/shell configuration/npm works

... maybe? Like, you're not wrong, but you maybe want to think/learn about it a bit more deeply, especially if you're interested in coding and security. I only say this because you seem to be worried about the right vulnerability but not what I would consider the right threats :). (I'm answering a few years after the question was posed, so maybe you're an expert on this stuff by now.)

Any program that you run in your own account can access **any** files that *you* own! If you have any sensitive information in your files, the malicious code doesn't need to be root. *It just needs you to run it once.*

(Don't do *any* of your development work with `sudo` or root on your own machine. There are actually a number of additional threats that root privileges enable; my focus on the files was mostly to suggest that in a certain sense, things might be worse than you think, to the point where the specific concerns that you are talking about are trivial.)

The ideas others have already mentioned (use a container / different user), or using a different host completely, are pretty much all just ways to make sure that your personal data never gets exposed to the risky code.

Also: if you don't trust it, then whatever you do, **do not include it as a dependency in your own programs!** If it's malicious, it will hurt everyone you distribute it to.

Answer (score -1):

Why does npm need a home directory? Glancing at /etc/passwd on one of my systems, I see a number of processes have their home directory set to root ("/"), /dev/null, or another directory not under /home (e.g. /sbin).

If you did that, there would be no ~/.zshrc file, & the process's environment would inherit the settings from /etc/zshrc.

Comment: This is misleading at best -- adding an entry to /etc/passwd doesn't do anything to change what happens if you run `npm`, unless you do a whole lot of other things first, which are pretty complicated and error-prone, and the OP is clearly not in a position to know what they are, ... plus it's really not suitable for a tool like npm which has a lot of expectations/assumptions built into it.